# Silverlight WCF RIA Include

Tags: wcf, silverlight, include, ria

In my Silverlight Applcication using RIA Services I have to use `[Include]` in the metadata file and `ObjectContext.Include("WhatEver")` in the DomainServiceClass file.

Can someone please explain to me why either one of them by itself is not enough?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Association Attribute is missing. With [Include] use [Association] (in the two related Entities, with the same name for the first parameter).

here an example

```
class Toto
{


public int? Id
{
get;
set;
}

[Include]
[Association("Titi_Toto", "Id", "TotoId")]
public IList<Titi> TitiList
{
get;
set;
}

}

....

class Titi
{


public int? Id
{
get;
set;
}

public int? TotoId
{
get;
set;
}

[Include]
[Association("Titi_Toto", "TotoId", "Id", IsForeighKey=True)]
public Toto TotoRef
{
get;
set;
}

}
```